# Android moving images on touch listener crash

Tags: android, imageview

*THIS VERSION IS CORRECT, I FOUND THE ANSWER!*

I have found this code on the internet. The problem is when I try to run it it crashes down. It's difficult to know the mistake.. The basic is to move multiple images independently. The emulator just says : "project has crashed". It doesnt even open my main activity. Which is this code :

```
      package com.example.disneyfan;


public class Cinderella extends Activity {

ImageView cinderella, dress;
int windowwidth;
int windowheight;
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1,
        layoutParams2;
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.disneyfan.R.id.cinderella);

    windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    System.out.println("width" + windowwidth);
    System.out.println("height" + windowheight);

    cinderella = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.cinderelladoll);
    cinderella.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) cinderella
                    .getLayoutParams();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                System.out.println("value of x" + x_cord);
                System.out.println("value of y" + y_cord);

                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams1.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams1.topMargin = y_cord - 25;
                cinderella.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    dress = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dress);
    dress.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) dress
                    .getLayoutParams();
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                System.out.println("value of x1" + x_cord);
                System.out.println("value of y1" + y_cord);

                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams2.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams2.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                dress.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Put up the output from logcat when the app crashes

Comment: I have put it up now. Can you help me?

Comment: What is line 37 of cinderella it says nullpointerexception

Comment: I found my mistake! It was silly. I made a mistake here : cinderella = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.cinderelladoll);

Comment: Glad you found the solution, don't forget to put in your answer and mark it correct, there's a lot of guidelines and everything to be able to keep asking questions and all, have a nice day